# "Der kleine Prinz" and short children novels vocabulary list

Tags: vocabulary, resource

Any ideas on where I can obtain vocabulary lists for famous children novels? I find it easier to memorize the list of words and then practice it by reading the novel it refers to. Instead of translating word by word.

I could achieve that by parsing the texts in C++ or python but I would prefer if someone else has done the work. Maybe some website that I couldn't find.

Comment: okay, I removed other, glücklich?

Comment: I agree with @Carsten. Saint-Exupéry definitely had children in mind when he wrote _J’ai une autre excuse: cette grande personne peut tout comprendre, même les livres pour enfants_ (I have another excuse: this big person can understand everything, even books for children.)

Comment: To make this clear (it has been indirectly said already): _Der kleine Prinz_ is not originally in German, but in French, so it might be a bit difficult to find an English-German dictionary for this book.

Answer (score 4):

The code is quite straightforward. In this case, you'll have to feed the entire TXT. Python 2.7:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -

import string
exclude = set(string.punctuation)  # punctuation to remove

from collections import defaultdict
word_dict = defaultdict(int)       # word list to fill

def get_words(intext):
    outtext = ''.join(ch for ch in intext if ch not in exclude)  # remove punctuation
    for word in outtext.split():  # loop over all words
        word_dict[word.lower()] += 1   # add word to list, increment 1

    return word_dict

text = """
FÜR LÉON WERTH

Entschuldigt bitte, dass ich dieses Kinderbuch einem Erwachsenen widme. Das hat nämlich einen wichtigen Grund: Er ist der beste Freund, den ich in der Welt habe. Ich habe einen weiteren Grund: Er versteht alles, auch die Bücher für Kinder. Ich habe auch noch einen dritten Grund: Er wohnt in Frankreich, wo er hungert und friert. Er muss wirklich getröstet werden. Wenn euch diese Gründe allesamt nicht genügen, widme ich das Buch dem Kind, das dieser Erwachsene einmal war. Alle großen Leute waren einmal Kinder (aber nur wenige erinnern sich daran). So verbessere ich also meine Widmung:

FÜR LÉON WERTH
ALS ER EIN JUNGE WAR

Die vorliegende Übersetzung ist urheberrechtlich geschützt. Der Gebrauch des Textes ist ausschließlich für private Zwecke, für eine nichtkommerzielle Nutzung gestattet. Eine kommerzielle Nutzung der Inhalte ganz oder in Teilen ist ausgeschlossen und ist nur nach ausdrücklich schriftlicher Genehmigung des Urhebers gestattet.
"""

print get_words(text)
```

Gives as an output the unique words and their frequency

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'verbessere': 1, 'bücher': 1, 'gebrauch': 1, 'urhebers': 1, 'nach': 1, 'kinderbuch': 1, 'get
röstet': 1, 'erwachsenen': 1, 'freund': 1, 'einem': 1, 'ausschließlich': 1, 'noch': 1, 'urheberrechtlich': 1, 'gestattet
': 2, 'habe': 3, 'diese': 1, 'werden': 1, 'die': 2, 'dieses': 1, 'inhalte': 1, 'werth': 2, 'übersetzung': 1, 'allesamt':
 1, 'meine': 1, 'das': 3, 'kinder': 2, 'vorliegende': 1, 'nur': 2, 'sich': 1, 'textes': 1, 'also': 1, 'alle': 1, 'schrif
tlicher': 1, 'muss': 1, 'großen': 1, 'dritten': 1, 'zwecke': 1, 'war': 2, 'wohnt': 1, 'grund': 3, 'nichtkommerzielle': 1
, 'beste': 1, 'genügen': 1, 'erinnern': 1, 'friert': 1, 'nutzung': 2, 'wichtigen': 1, 'welt': 1, 'für': 5, 'ganz': 1, 'v
ersteht': 1, 'oder': 1, 'hungert': 1, 'wirklich': 1, 'nämlich': 1, 'teilen': 1, 'erwachsene': 1, 'dieser': 1, 'euch': 1,
 'gründe': 1, 'alles': 1, 'genehmigung': 1, 'entschuldigt': 1, 'er': 6, 'und': 2, 'ausdrücklich': 1, 'eine': 2, 'weitere
n': 1, 'dass': 1, 'private': 1, 'einmal': 2, 'léon': 2, 'widmung': 1, 'so': 1, 'wo': 1, 'in': 3, 'der': 4, 'ein': 1, 'de
m': 1, 'ausgeschlossen': 1, 'des': 2, 'geschützt': 1, 'wenige': 1, 'nicht': 1, 'kind': 1, 'ich': 6, 'wenn': 1, 'kommerzi
elle': 1, 'daran': 1, 'hat': 1, 'leute': 1, 'widme': 2, 'als': 1, 'ist': 5, 'junge': 1, 'bitte': 1, 'einen': 3, 'auch':
2, 'buch': 1, 'waren': 1, 'den': 1, 'frankreich': 1, 'aber': 1})
```

---

*NB*: I made everything lower-case, which is not a great practice, especially for German.